# Rebasing branch containing closed gerrit reviews

Tags: git, gerrit

Gerrit version: 2.6.1

Here is the situation.

1. branch_a and branch_b are created from same commit of master branch from gerrit UI.
2. 3 commits are pushed + gerrit-reviewed on branch_a
3. 4 commits are pushed + gerrit-reviewed on branch_b
4. branch_b is rebased on last commit of branch_a on a client machine.
5. While pushing changes to refs/for/branch_b, gerrit (correctly) complains that 4 (rebase'd) commits have already been closed. (based on change-id in the commit message)

What is the best way to rebase branch_b on branch_a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't typically rebase changes that have been reviewed in Gerrit.  See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing - 'Do not rebase commits that you have pushed to a public repository.'

Instead, you probably want to merge the changes from branch_a into branch_b.

```
git checkout branch_b
git merge branch_a
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch_b
```

This will create a merge commit and push it to review on Gerrit.

Comment: Your answer is a possible solution, but in our case, we don't want to create a merge commit on branch_b. In normal course of action, we would merge branch_a into master (when branch_a is released to prod) and then rebase branch_b onto master and continue work on it. In this particular situation, we want code from branch_a to be available in branch_b without a merge commit. I think this would have been possible if gerrit was not in picture.